# Simulating Chrome Browser TLS/SSL handshake in java

Tags: java, ssl, fingerprint, handshake

Is there a java library which can do the same as [go library utls](https://github.com/refraction-networking/utls)?

I want to simulate in java the TLS/SSL handshake of a Chrome or Firefox browser.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "simulate TLS handshake of Chrome or Firefox browser". Each of those browsers has their own TLS library with their own idiosyncrasies. They are not even equivalent to each other, let alone another TLS library. What's important is that they comply with the relevant RFC and can thus securely interoperate with other implementations. Java has the SSLSocket, SSLServerSocket, SSLEngine and other supporting SSL classes to implements SSL/TLS.

Comment: Please have a look at https://github.com/refraction-networking/utls/blob/master/u_parrots.go. The go library can dynamically specify things like CipherSuites , extensions during SSL client hello, while if we use java SSLEngine , these things are almost fixed , which means your TLS finger printing is fixed and it's not like any browser TLS finger print at all. So I want to know if there is a java library which can support specifying CipherSuites , extensions during SSL client hello to pretend that I'm a browser , not java. The utls library of go can do things like this.